# row wise comparison between a vector and a matrix in r

Tags: r, date-comparison

I have two datasets from 10 people. One is a vector, and the other is a matrix. What I want to see is if the first element of the vector includes in the first row of the matrix, and if the second element of the vector includes in the second row of the matrix, and so on.

so, I changed the vector into a matrix and used `apply` to compare them row-wise. But, the result was not that correct.

Here is the datasets.

```
df1<-matrix(c(rep(0,10),2,4,7,6,5,7,4,2,2,2),ncol=2)
df1
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    2
# [2,]    0    4
# [3,]    0    7
# [4,]    0    6
# [5,]    0    5
# [6,]    0    7
# [7,]    0    4
# [8,]    0    2
# [9,]    0    2
#[10,]    0    2

df2<-c(1,3,6,4,1,3,3,2,2,5)
df2<-as.matrix(df2)
apply(df2, 1, function(x) any(x==df1))
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

However, the result must be all `FALSE` but 8th and 9th.
Can anyone correct the function? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few approaches you could take

1. Two calls to apply

   ```
   # 
   # 1 by column to check if the values are equal
   # then by row to see if any rows contain TRUE
   apply(apply(df1,2,`==`,df2),1,any)
   ```
2. Use sapply and `seq_along`

   ```
   sapply(seq_along(df2), function(x, y, i) y[i] %in% x[i, ], y = df2 ,x = df1)
   ```
3. repeat df2 to the same length as `df1` and then compare

   ```
    rowSums(df1==rep(df2, length = length(df1))) > 0
   ```

Answer (score 7):

This vectorized code should be very efficient:

```
> as.logical( rowSums(df1==df2))
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I always forget that matrices are filled/compared column-wise

Comment: I'm getting `Error in df1 == df2 : non-conformable arrays`, do you happen to know why?

Comment: Because df2 is data.frame and has dimensions. `as.logical(rowSums(df1==as.numeric(df2)))` should work.